# AWS Amplify Cognito Auth error in Android app

Tags: android, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am following the Amplify docs for adding Authentication to my Android app. I'm getting an `AuthException` on this line:

```kotlin
Amplify.addPlugin(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
```

I do have a user pool created. Do I need to attach it somehow? There is some problem with the `AWSMobileClient`, I guess.

Here's my `Application` class:

```kotlin
class AppUtils : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        try {
            Amplify.addPlugin(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            Amplify.configure(applicationContext)
            Log.d(TAG, "Initialized Amplify")
        } catch (error: AmplifyException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not initialize Amplify", error)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error that shows up in logcat:

> AuthException{message=Failed to instantiate AWSMobileClient, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: Neither Cognito Identity or Cognito UserPool was used. At least one must be present to use AWSMobileClient., recoverySuggestion=See attached exception for more details}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That error indicates that there was no Identity or UserPool found in your configuration file.

First make sure you've completed the following steps:

- amplify init
- amplify add auth
- amplify push

Once complete, you should have an `amplifyconfiguration.json` and an `awsconfiguration.json` in your `app/src/main/res/raw` directory.

Your `amplifyconfiguration.json` should look like this:

```
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "auth": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
                "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
                "Version": "0.1.0",
                "IdentityManager": {
                    "Default": {}
                },
                "CredentialsProvider": {
                    "CognitoIdentity": {
                        "Default": {
                            "PoolId": "us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            "Region": "us-east-1"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "CognitoUserPool": {
                    "Default": {
                        "PoolId": "us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx",
                        "AppClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "AppClientSecret":
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "Region": "us-east-1"
                    }
                },
                "Auth": {
                    "Default": {
                        "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your `awsconfiguration.json` should look like this:

```
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
    "Version": "0.1.0",
    "IdentityManager": {
        "Default": {}
    },
    "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "Region": "us-east-1"
            }
        }
    },
    "CognitoUserPool": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx",
            "AppClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "AppClientSecret":
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Region": "us-east-1"
        }
    },
    "Auth": {
        "Default": {
            "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same error for few days, you just have added basic files to the project and now you need to define user pools for Amplify to add more data to both config files. You need to run these commands it will fix this issue.

```
amplify init // It will make sure you have basic setup added
amplify add auth // It will add auth data and user pools to config files
amplify push // It will push all the setup to amplify cloud
```

Hope it will fix your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have just added Cognito, run

```
amplify update api
```

to use Cognito as the auth mode.

Then run

```
amplify push
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.The problem is when I was configuring in the terminal the sign in method.

There are 3 supported sign in methods:

1. signIn (username - password sign in via your own native UI)
2. signInWithWebUi (username - password sign in through a hosted UI webview)
3. signInWithSocialWebUi - (sign in with Google, Facebook, etc)

For (1), you need to choose "Default Configuration". Once complete, run amplify push. At this point, you should expect NOT to have an OAuth object in your amplifyconfiguration.json.
For (2) or (3), you need to choose "Default configuration with Social Provider (Federation)". Admittedly, the wording is probably a little confusing, since (2) is not a social provider. At this point, you SHOULD expect to have an OAuth object in your amplifyconfiguration.json

To update this use:

```
sudo amplify update auth
```

Choose the correct sign in method and

```
sudo amplify push
```

If you get this error when using the sign in method 2: **Can't fill in URI in "amplify add auth"**

Use this uris:
(https://www.amazon.com/ or http://localhost:3000/)

Or

Type **gettingstarted://**